# How to select and group by different number of columns based on condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my `WHERE` clause there are "groups" of selections separated by `OR`, for example:

```
WHERE (group_='g1' AND unit='u1' AND department='d1')
   OR (group_='g25' AND unit='u54' AND department='d70' AND team='t88')
```

or

```
WHERE (group_='g1' AND unit='u1' AND department='d1')
   OR (group_='g25' AND unit='u54' AND department='d70' AND team='t88')
   OR (group_='g3' AND unit='u12')
```

Each of these groups may have different number of columns so some can be `null`. That's why I want to `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the selected columns.

I tried this:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN team IS NULL
        THEN group_, unit, department
      
        WHEN team IS NULL AND department IS NULL
        THEN group_, unit

        WHEN team IS NULL AND department IS NULL AND unit IS NULL
        THEN group_

        ELSE
          group_, unit, department, team
    END

    COUNT(CASE WHEN status='active' then 1 END) AS active_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status='inactive' then 1 END) AS inactive_count

FROM my_table
WHERE (group_='g1' AND unit='u1' AND department='d1')
   OR (group_='g25' AND unit='u54' AND department='d70' AND team='t88')
   OR (group_='g3' AND unit='u6')
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN team IS NULL
        THEN group_, unit, department
      
        WHEN team IS NULL AND department IS NULL
        THEN group_, unit

        WHEN team IS NULL AND department IS NULL AND unit IS NULL
        THEN group_

        ELSE
          group_, unit, department, team
    END
ORDER BY group_
```

But this is clearly wrong. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/X7PBwchn

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

I have the following data:

| id | username | group | unit | department | team | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t1 | active |
| 2 | user2 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t2 | active |
| 3 | user3 | g1 | u1 | d1 | t3 | inactive |
| 4 | user4 | g3 | u6 | d12 | t30 | active |
| 5 | user5 | g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 | inactive |

And I need to count `active` and `inactive` users based on each selection inside each group in the `WHERE` clause:

| group | unit | department | team | active_count | inactive_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g1 | u1 | d1 | NULL | 2 | 1 |
| g25 | u54 | d70 | t88 | 1 | 0 |
| g3 | u6 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Please provide the expected results for your sample data

Comment: @Stu thanks, I added example to the bottom of the post. If you understood the logic then maybe you may see that I need a completely different query? In fact I have a working query that achieves my goal, however it uses many `UNION`s and I think it's not efficient. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/Nv2csSc8

Comment: Actually splitting several `or` conditions into a unioned query is often the more performant option as each query can properly implement a seek on a supporting index.

Comment: Oh good to know! In my case I might get dozens of these "OR"s (each of these groups inside the `OR` is a selection made in the frontend). Do you think that it will be alright even when there are.. say 50+ of these?

Comment: There is no one fits-all answer, you would need to test and compare the execution plans and pay attention primarily to logical reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix your needed-NULL values to be NULL through `CASE` expressions and manage to do it correctly, you can apply aggregation directly.

```
SELECT [group], [unit],
       CASE WHEN NOT ([group] = 'g3' AND [unit] = 'u6') 
            THEN [department] END AS [department],
       CASE WHEN NOT ([group] = 'g3' AND [unit] = 'u6') 
             AND NOT ([group] = 'g1' AND [unit] = 'u1' AND [department] = 'd1')
            THEN [team] END AS [team],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [status] = 'active' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [active_count],
       SUM(CASE WHEN [status] = 'inactive' 
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [inactive_count]
FROM tab
WHERE ([group]='g1'  AND [unit]='u1'  AND [department]='d1')
   OR ([group]='g25' AND [unit]='u54' AND [department]='d70' AND [team]='t88')
   OR ([group]='g3'  AND [unit]='u6')
GROUP BY [group], [unit],
         CASE WHEN NOT ([group] = 'g3' AND [unit] = 'u6') 
              THEN [department] END,
         CASE WHEN NOT ([group] = 'g3' AND [unit] = 'u6') 
               AND NOT ([group] = 'g1' AND [unit] = 'u1' AND [department] = 'd1')
              THEN [team] END
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/i7YVx_PW).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid copypasting groupings i'd create a cross apply with all your needed values:

```sql
SELECT
    
    gg.group_, gg.unit, gg.department, gg.team,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status='active' then 1 END) AS active_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status='inactive' then 1 END) AS inactive_count

FROM my_table m
cross apply (
    select 1 AS groupType, group_, unit, department, null as team
    where (group_='g1' AND unit='u1' AND department='d1')
    union all
    select 2, group_, unit, department, team
    where   (group_='g25' AND unit='u54' AND department='d70' AND team='t88')
    union all
    select 3, group_, unit, null, null
    where (group_='g3' AND unit='u6')
    ) gg
GROUP BY
    gg.groupType, gg.group_, gg.unit, gg.department, gg.team
ORDER BY gg.group_
```

This should probably simplify your code generation as well